# /(.+)\n\1/ works but /(.*)\n\1/ doesn't when they should both work

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I was playing around with `sed` after answering another question and I noticed that `.+` and `.*` are not giving the same result *when they both match multiple characters* in a context address.
The following command<sup>1</sup>:

```
sed -E '$!N;/(.+)\n\1/!P;D' <<IN
one
one_more
two
two_more
IN
```

prints

```
one_more
two_more
```

OK, that's the expected output.
Changing the regex from `.+` to `.*` (i.e. from *one or more characters* to *zero or more characters*) should give the same result but it does not:

```
sed -E '$!N;/(.*)\n\1/!P;D' <<IN
one
one_more
two
two_more
IN
```

prints just one line

```
two_more
```

What's going on here ?

---

<sup>1: I'm using ERE for simplicity/readability, the same happens when using BRE</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That happens because `/(.*)\n\1/` is also matching a simple newline (`\n`: empty string, followed by newline, followed by the *same* empty string from the beginning).

So it will also match the string `one_more\ntwo` from your example.

To avoid that, you'll have to anchor your regexps, e.g. `sed -E '$!N;/^(.+)\n\1/!P;D'` or `sed -E '$!N;/^(.*)\n\1/!P;D'`.

Comment: But wouldn't that contradict greediness?

Comment: No. It's simply that `"one_more\ntwo"` will match `/(.*)\n\1/`, whether greedy or not. To understand what happens in that `sed` script, add a debugging command after the `N` eg: `sed -E '$!N; {h;s/(.|\n)*/<<&>>/p;x}; /(.*)\n\1/!P; D' ...`

Comment: @RudiC - _greedy_ means the regex engine attempts to match _as much as possible_; in this particular case (`(.*)\n\1`) _nothing_ (the empty string) followed by newline and again by _nothing_ matches and that is sufficient.

Comment: @RudiC `one_more\ntwo` doesn't match `/(.+)\n\1/` at all (since there's no non-empty string that appears on both sides of the NL), but it does match `/(.*)\n\1/`. Then again, `one_more\neno` would match `/(.+)\n\1/` too, so perhaps the anchors are a good idea.